# Why does defining a class in Python 2.7, without inheriting an object, not result in a __mro__ method?

Tags: python

I am working on [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite) with Python 2.7.9.

Here is what I have tried:

1. Define a class

   ```
   class A:
       def test(self):
           print "test"
   ```

   Then run

   ```
   A.__mro__
   ```

   Then I got

   ```
   >>> A.__mro__
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__mro__'
   ```
2. Then I define

   ```
   class B(object):
       def test(self):
           print "test"
   ```

   Then run

   ```
   B.__mro__
   ```

   Then I got

   ```
   >>> B.__mro__
   (<class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
   ```

What is the different between the two definitions?

I found that in Python 3, the edition without "object" still has the `__mro__` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__mro__` is only defined for [new-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python).  In Python 2, a class is only new-style if it inherits from `object` (or from a built in type, which in turn inherits from `object`), while all classes in Python 3 are new-style no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The `__mro__` is only defined for *new style classes*, those that inherit from Python `object`.

In Python 3, *all* classes are new-style classes. They inherit from `object` implicitly. In other words, old-style Python 2 classes have been removed from the language.